Problem selecting a "check-box" with python Selenium: click() launches the link in the HTML code
I am automating with Selenium & python some searches in a website (https://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/hd/es/advanced). Most of it is already done but one specific step I am still doing manually, and for this I'd appreciate your support.
The difficulty is not with the identification of the element, but that element.click() calls a link inside the element instead of ticking the associated box.
Let me show first one field on which the click() option works. The HTML code of the section "AÑO" (year) is for one of the years (1683):
<div class="parameter-row-unchecked-ok-empty"> <img alt="1683" class="parameter-check" src="/fs/static/img/check-off.png"><p class="parameter-paragraph">1683</p></div>


Although the HTML code does not have any "input" or "checkbox" tags, the code driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath).click() works well and selects the element/ticks the box. I note that element.is_activated() does not work, but element.get_attribute(class) allows to identify the status.
The part with which I am having problems is the following (TÍTULO = title). The HTML code is:
<div class="parameter-row-unchecked-ok-empty"><img alt="25352831" class="parameter-check" src="/fs/static/img/check-off.png" title="Esta obra es de acceso restringido. Puede acceder a ella en ordenadores específicos de las instalaciones de la BNE."><p class="parameter-paragraph"><a href="card?sid=25352831">25 División</a></p></div>


Note that inside the <p> tag there is a href attribute whose URL is called whenever I run driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath).click(). I have tried with the inner and outer xpaths, but it does not matter: either an error is raised because the xpath is not clickable, or the new page is opened instead of the box being ticked.
So far I have automated all the data input (except for this) and the output gathering. Any suggestion is welcome!
[edit: examples of xpaths I've used: xpath = '//*[@id="parameter-div-sid"]/div[18]' or, longer version, xpath = '/html/body/section[2]/div/form[1]/fieldset[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[18]'

Share a code snippet of the selector you have tried.

Added as edit comment.

I have used wait and try to click it's working please select wait as per your browser loading time of checkboxes
import java.time.Duration;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class ClickCheckBox {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/hd/es/advanced");
    
    //  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@alt='1637']")).click();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
        WebElement element = wait.until(
                ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//img[@alt='1637']")));
        element.click();
    }
}


Thanks. No, it is not consistently working: some times it does, other times it does not and opens the linked URL. I have tried with visibility and presence:     element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, nam_xpath)))
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, nam_xpath)))
element.click()
